# Make GridLayoutManager VERTICAL orientation with horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I need the RecyclerView Gridlayout Manager with horizontal scrollable behavior. It must add child views like it does when it has VERTICAL orientation (column wise index for e.g. (row 1, col 1) = index 0, (row 1, col 2) = index 1 and so on).

Currently VERTICAL Orientation does not allow to scroll horizontally and fits child view with in device width.

**Edit:**

I have 100 rows and 150 columns in RecyclerView GridLayoutManager and need horizontal scrolling of view. I am hiding and showing of rows, which is only possible with VERTICAL Orientation.

Comment: When you create a new Resource Layout you get qualifiers such as language, orientation, screen size. In your case orientation is one of these. In the manifest you can force orientation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Orientation of activity in manifest file is "landscape" mode. Problem is with RecyclerView GridLayoutManager orientation behavior.

Comment: @Gaurav Did you got any potential solution with RecyclerView & GridLayout Manager.?

Comment: @Gaurav have you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put your `Recyclerview` inside a `HorizontalScrollingView` and disable the vertical scrolling for your `Recyclerview`:

Your .xml file may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myHorizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </HorizontalScrollView >

</LinearLayout >
```

In your code you have to override `canScrollVertically` of your `GridLayoutManager`:

Java:

```
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 100) {
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Kotlin:

```
val mLayoutManager = object : GridLayoutManager(this, 100) {
    override fun canScrollVertically() : Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

It is possible that the 100 rows are too much to display them at once on your screen. To solve this, just don't deactivate the vertical scrolling in the `GridLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Here 1 counts as number of rows. use `getActvity`() if you work with fragment, and `MainActivity.this` for example if you re calling it in the activity

Comment: Rainmaker, Thanks for answer, Above code will allow horizontal scrolling but I have many rows in layout and assign index vertically(Row wise). I need index horizontally.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand what you mean, put the number of rows u need (5,10)....you cannot scroll endlessly vertically and horizontally at the same time